# Double click on mobile doesn't work on an iPad

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I'd like to implement a double click event using jQuery but it works only on computer, it doesn't work on iPad...

My event :

```
$('td').on('dblclick', function(e) {
  console.log('test');
});
```

Comment: Theres a shim you can use for the event listener of dbltap since dblclick isn't possible on mobile devices. Read this article it'll help you understand more plus with the 300ms delay. http://briangonzalez.org/posts/mouse-and-touch-events-done-right

Comment: Ok, thank you EasyBB. I was thinking that it was an issue with my code... And, is there a plugin ?

Comment: Yes there is http://davidwalsh.name/pointer-event  please make sure you read this very well.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work on mobile is because there is no `dblclick` event listener for mobile devices, there is hover a `dbltap` event listener as well as many others that differentiate to it's desktop counterpart.

Please read this for understanding mobile events and the 300ms delay that you'll commonly find: briangonzalez.org/posts/mouse-and-touch-events-done-right

And for a plugin here is `pointer.js` davidwalsh.name/pointer-event

**EX**:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
element.addEventListener('pointerclick',function(e){
  //run following code
});
```

There is also another plugin for just mobile detection since there are only few events yet 100s of gestures. It looks intriguing

http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/